# if it was built to help rather than harm

Tags: conditional-constructions, if

How do we make sense of the boldfaced if-clause? It's at odds with the traditional conception of conditional sentences, which would require a matching main clause containing "would," 'could," etc. But there's none here.

The resultant product has “visco-elastic properties” — meaning that it behaves like a liquid or a solid depending on the level of the force applied. Think of a fun-sized liquid metal T-1000 from “Terminator 2,” **if it was built to help rather than harm**.

Source:
https://nypost.com/2022/04/04/robot-slime-magnet-could-save-lives-by-searching-our-insides/

Comment: It makes sense if you delete "**if it was**".

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you. Do you mean the original is poorly written?

Comment: I haven't seen 'Terminator 2', but the sentence asks you to imagine what a 'fun-sized' T-1000 _would be like_ if it was intended to be helpful rather than harmful.

Comment: @KateBunting That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yeah; it's just a way of saying "imagine [something familiar/known], *but* [with these distinctions]". The "if it was" plays the role of "but" or "except". So, "imagine a [T-1000, a ruthless killing machine, sometimes having a solid shape, sometimes appearing as a liquid], *except* [it's not a killing machine].

Comment: @Apollyon I find it a little awkward. I would prefer it without "if it was".

Comment: @KateBunting  Could the two clauses of the sentence in question be switched around as follows, assuming that the "was" is actually a non-standard subjunctive?

a. _If a fun-sized liquid metal T-1000 from “Terminator 2” was built to help rather than harm, think of it._

b. _If T-1000 from “Terminator 2” was built to help rather than harm, think of a fun-sized liquid version of it._

Comment: Not really. It's natural to put _Think of_ at the beginning, to alert the reader that they are being asked to compare the product  with something familiar to them (assuming they have seen the film!). Then the proviso, one way in which the two are different, is added afterwards.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you think the original OP sentence is natural?

Comment: Well... It's clear to me what it means (except that I'd never heard of T-1000!), but maybe the version I suggested above is clearer.

Comment: @KateBunting Could the "was" be replaced by "were" in the OP sentence?

Comment: _If it were..._ (the subjunctive) is strictly correct, but would seem a bit incongruous with the informal beginning _Think of..._

Comment: Think of what the import of your question might be,  if it was designed to impress rather than inform? [same structure]. Just saying. [See what Jeff says below.]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not a particularly well written sentence, but there is nothing wrong with attaching a conditional to an imperative clause.

> Don’t marry him if you don’t love him.

> Avoid a dog if it is growling.

We do not add modals to imperatives.

Comment: The issue is the counterfactual if-clause. Your examples are normal because their if-clauses are not counterfactual. But the OP sentence is different.

Comment: @Apollyon If an assertion is factual if it is not normally preceded by “if.” There is no way to determine whether my examples are factual or hypothetical. There is no special rule for imperatives based on a counter-factual. “Be sure to take a photo if you see a blue unicorn.” I do not like the quoted sentence as written, but the absence of “would” heading an imperative verb is acceptable and does not interfere with classifying the subordinate clause as a conditional clause.

Comment: The opposite of "counterfactual" in English grammar is not "factual," but rather "possible." There might be no rules prohibiting imperatives joined by a counterfactual in standard reference works, but native speakers seem to have qualms about such sentences.

Comment: That goes to show there is an implicit "rule" in your mental grammar that prohibits them.

Comment: Those who feel there's nothing wrong about the OP sentence actually map "a fun-sized liquid metal T-1000 from Terminator 2" onto the clause, "what a 'fun-sized' T-1000 would be like." And the clause fits perfectly with "if it was built to help rather than harm."

Comment: First, I am a native speaker. Second, I explicitly have said that I did not like the sentence several times. Third, the premise of the question was that the main clause must contain a modal if it complements a conditional clause. This is a false premise as I have shown through **three** examples, one of which clearly cannot refer to something possible. Reliance on an “implicit,” “mental” rule that is not found “in standard reference works” and contradicts grammatical examples is no way to clarify English for learners. It is a sloppy sentence, but not for the reason cited by the OP.

Comment: Are you referring to " “Be sure to take a photo if you see a blue unicorn"? What does the sentence presuppose? Does it presuppose a blue unicorn is a possible creature or not?  Compare " “Be sure to take a photo if you **saw** a blue unicorn," which is comparble to the OP sentence.

Comment: Note I am not arguing against the absence of a modal in the main clause when it is accompanied by an if-clause in an **across-the-board manner**.

Comment: If you think  “Be sure to take a photo if you see a blue unicorn" clearly refers to something impossible, isn't that because you are viewing it as a detached god-like being, that is, the author or reader of a fairy tale, where such sentences actually presuppose something possible?

Comment: @Apollyon You and I agree on at least one thing, namely that the quoted sentence is not good. “Fun-sized” for “toy-sized”? “Think” for “imagine”? Where we disagree is that the OP’s question clearly did imply “across the board.” We also have a disagreement that I suspect is relatively unimportant. You are correct that Imperatives are rarely associated with definitely counter-factual hypotheses. But that is not because of some heretofore unknown rule of grammar. It is because it very seldom makes sense except as sarcasm or hyperbole.